# File upload not working on wamp server?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am working on a project where you have to upload all files on a server in JPEG format but this following code in upload.php is not working, like it is not checking the condition whether there is a name to album or not.

Following file is upload.php with database connect to it with 4 fields in table... `id`, `name`, `album_id`, `url`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP file upload</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<div id="body">
  <?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>
    <div id="container">
    <h3>Upload</h3>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $album_id = $_POST['album'];
            $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            if(empty($name) || empty($file)){
                echo "Please Fill ALL THE FUIELD ";
            }else{
                echo "working";
            }
        }



        ?>
        Name : <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br  /> <br  />
        Select Folder : <br />
        <select>
            <?php 
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT id , name FROM albums");
                while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $album_id = $run['id'];
                    $album_name = $run['name'];
                    echo "<option value='$album_id'> $album_name </option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        Select File : <br />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which line is not working? plz post your html as well

Comment: Does your `<form />` element have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute ?

Comment: @roberto06 yeah it is having enctype="multipart/form-data";

Comment: @SinaMiandashti that whole code is not working i guess.. wait i will post html code ..!!

Comment: Please share the HTML form and the error log.

Comment: You will need to post your form as well

Comment: @roberto06 check the code

Comment: @SinaMiandashti check the code

Comment: @PrasenWahane I answered, looks like it wase a simple case-sensitive situation.

Answer (score 0):

file type and size haven't defined and upload config array did not initialize

Comment: that is not required i guess ?

Answer (score 0):

The keys in `$_POST` are case-sensitive, you're checking for `Upload` but your input name is `upload`.

You should either change your `input` to :

```
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
```

Or your first PHP check to :

```
if (isset($_POST['Upload'])) {
```

Also, you should set a `name` attribute for your `select` or it won't be sent.